# Module not found: Can't resolve SCSS files from example

Tags: reactjs, typescript, office-ui-fabric

I'm trying to run React typescript project with UI Fabric and every time i try to run the project i got this error

```
Failed to compile
./src/Controls/SideBarLeft.tsx
Module not found: Can't resolve 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/components/Nav/examples/Nav.Basic.Example.scss'
```

Comment: did you run "npm i office-ui-fabric-react" ?

Comment: yes i tried and it didn't work

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Sorry for being late, i'm using "office-ui-fabric-react": "^6.203.3"

Comment: Okay well that's a legacy version of that package so make sure you are reading the right docs: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/wiki/Legacy-Branches

Comment: i will upgrade the version and try, thank you for your help

Comment: That wiki page actually is meant for contributors, not consumers (consuming v6 and v7 is pretty much the same). But if you have the option of upgrading to version 7, it's definitely a good idea.